# How to setup Selenium with headless Firefox on Raspbian Buster

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, geckodriver, debian-buster

I have gotten this to work in Jessie/Stretch with previous Firefox versions but can't seem to get it to work with Raspberry Pi 3B or 4 running Raspbian Buster and the latest Selenium, 3.141.0 in Python.

Since iceweasel is no longer available I install `firefox-esr` via apt and get the latest ARM geckodriver, which is currently 0.23.0, from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases then run the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver', capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print(driver.page_source)
driver.close()
display.stop()
```

This returns the error:

```
Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpxMUUcF If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SeleniumDebugExample.py", line 50, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='/srv/main/geckodriver', capabilities=capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 73, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 114, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpxMUUcF If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I am specifying geckodriver though so I am not sure what the issue is...

If anyone has gotten headless selenium to work on Raspbian Buster and can share some could it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you reduce the scope of your question to either **Chrome** or **Firefox**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bunch of testing it seems the issue was with adding the marrionette=False capability...  Back in Jessie with iceweasel I had needed to add that for it to work but it seems with firefox-esr that is no longer necessary...   I was able to get this working with just the below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print(driver.page_source)
driver.close()
display.stop()
```